# Quicksort in Elixir without using Enum.partition

Tags: elixir, quicksort

Is there possible to build a quicksort without using Enum.partition? I implemented this code using a filter, but I walk through the list twice to get the the other two. Can someone show me how to do this walking just one time on the list?

```
defmodule QuickSort do
  def sort([]) do
    []
  end
  def sort(l) do
    [head | tail] = l
    {l1, l2} = partition(head, tail)
    sort(l1) ++ [head] ++ sort(l2)
  end
  def partition(pivot, rest) do
    lesser = Enum.filter(rest, fn(x) -> x < pivot end)
    greater = Enum.filter(rest, fn(x) -> x >= pivot end)

    {lesser, greater}
 end                                                                           
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with just `Enum.filter/2`. This can be done with `Enum.reduce/2` like this:

```
list = [9, 7, 6, 8, 7, 3, 2, 1, 6]
pivot = 6
{lesser, greater} = Enum.reduce(list, {[], []}, fn x, {lesser, greater} ->
  if x < pivot do
    {[x | lesser], greater}
  else
    {lesser, [x | greater]}
  end
end)

IO.inspect {lesser, greater}
```

Output:

```
{[1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 9]}
```

But then we've basically reimplemented `Enum.partition/2` (except that our lists are reversed).